# navigation background image xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm new in xamarin(start using 2 week), now I need do a background Image wtih navigation bar like below picture? how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an `UIImage` in your `UIViewController` (filling whole or only top of ViewController) setting your `UINavigationBar` to a clear color with

```
    YourNavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
    YourNavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
    YourNavigationBar.Translucent = true;
    YourNavigationBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

To reset `UINavigationBar` transparency you have to use:

```
YourNavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(null, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```